# Adding .hidden-phone in an existing css file to hide background image

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I'm sure there is an easy answer to this one...

Using Twitter Bootstrap, I have this in my **style.css.erb** file:

```
.login_page body {height:100%;
        max-width:inherit;
        margin:0 20px;
        background-image: url(<%= image_path 'oap_dotlogo.png' %>);
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
            background-position: 5%, 80%;
        background-color: #E3F5FD;
    }
```

That is great, except on a phone where the background logo is a pain in the ass.  I'd like to drop that logo on a phone.

I see that **bootstrap-responsive.css** already defines the .hidden-phone:

```
@media (max-width: 767px) {
  .hidden-desktop {
    display: inherit !important;
  }
  .visible-desktop {
    display: none !important;
  }
  .visible-phone {
    display: inherit !important;
  }
  .hidden-phone {
    display: none !important;
  }
}
```

So, how do I modify the style.css.erb so that the background-image tag has the **.hidden-phone** class?

I've tried a few permutations of adding .hidden-phone in the style.css.erb but nothing seems to work - I must have the syntax wrong.

Thanks!
Dave

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you're confusing CSS and HTML here. When you say:

> [H]ow do I modify the style.css.erb so that the background-image tag has the .hidden-phone class?

... you can't add a class to a CSS declaration. You don't actually want to *hide* your element (the `body` in this case), rather at small screen sizes you want to modify the `background` property. So, within the media query that you already have, add this:

```
@media (max-width: 767px) {
  .login_page body { background-image: none; }
  ...
  all your other small-screen styles
}
```

Then, the default will be to show your `background-image` and you are removing it for small screens. If the image is large, you might consider a mobile-first approach. i.e. do the opposite, as @po228 mentioned - only add the `background-image` for larger viewport widths.

Comment: Hmmm,  I tried this *ALSO* and it had no impact.  The rest of the site seems to be quite responsive and adjusts properly on a phone.  I've reached out to the theme author with this question and I'll post an update here.

Comment: I stand corrected!  This technique did work perfectly when I added this to my style.css.erb just after the existing definition of .login_page.  Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you were very close. To define styles that won't be displayed on a phone you need to use min-width, not max-width. Try the following:

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
    .login_page body {
        background-image: url(<%= image_path 'oap_dotlogo.png' %>);
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-position: 5%, 80%;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks po228 and @Ed-M !  Part of the issue is I'm using a purchased theme (gebo admin from themeforest) and I'm trying to keep my changes "in the spirit" of that theme.  They had already defined all of the .login css in style.css (which I changed to a .erb) so I was hoping to only have to put the changes in that file...  The whole max-width chunk of that file was given to me in bootstrap-responsive.css which I assumed was "how it should be" :-).  I'll try some of these suggestions and respond.

Comment: Hmmm,  I tried this and it had no impact.  The rest of the site seems to be quite responsive and adjusts properly on a phone.  I've reached out to the theme author with this question and I'll post an update here.